# React Native WebView App CORS issue when connecting to local C# SignalR server :

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-signalr, react-native-webview

am currently working on a React Native WebView app where I've loaded HTML, CSS, and JS files locally to my Android project. Additionally, I have set up a local server on my laptop using C# and SignalR for communication.

However, when attempting to run the Android emulator and making a request to the server, I encounter a CORS error.

Can someone please guide me on how to effectively resolve the CORS error in this scenario? Any insights or examples specific to React Native WebView and a C# SignalR server would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to follow the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ecors6) to enable CORS on my server, but unfortunately, it hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does your Signalr project use https or http? If it's http, then it's a expected issue. [We can use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` for debugging.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562672/7687666)