Maui App consuming ASP.NET Core Web API is ok in Windows app , fails in Android app
I am new to Web API. I have written an ASP.NET Core Web API in VS 2022 to communicate with my SQL Server database.
This is my code:
using cd.Data;
using cd.ModelsCd;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace cd.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CdsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly cdContext _context;

        public CdsController(cdContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cds
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Cd>>> GetCd()
        {
            return await _context.Cd.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Cds/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cd>> GetCd(int id)
        {
            var cd = await _context.Cd.FindAsync(id);

            if (cd == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return cd;
        }
}

The code I used to get info is:
static async Task LectureAsync2()
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://WebApiCd:7134/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        // get 1 CD
        Console.WriteLine("GET 1 Cd");
        fich Cds1 = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Cds1 = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<fich>();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Cds1.CdNom);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

I have tried to use it with VS 2022 in a Windows console app => ok, in Windows .NET MAUI => ok, in VSD 2022 .NET MAUI Android emulator or Samsung s21 connected to my PC, the result is a .NET connection failure.
Network config is ok, because I have entered in the Samsung web browser http://webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11 and I get a good response.
Can you, please, indicate what I am doing wrong in Android?
Thanks in advance.

the result is a .NET connection failure what is the full and complete error message (as text, not screen shots)?

Seems likely you're trying to invoke network operations on the main UI thread which is something that Android doesn't permit.

The error message is : [DOTNET] Connection failure. If android does not allow to query directly a web api, what is the good practise for that. I am using dotnet 8. I will test this with dotnet 7 .

Android can still query web APIs and perform network I/O, just not on the main UI thread. i.e.: the UI thread should never be blocked waiting for operations to complete. In Android development time-consuming operations are meant to be run in an Activity (not an Activity running on the main UI thread) or in background services.

I was thinking that running task async allow to delay the time and does not block the main thread. Regarding your note, it's not the case. I do not know how to implement an Activity in VS 2022. Do you know a good tuto or example for this? Google give related info with android studio not with Visual studio.

I think this issue should be related to android (API level 28 or higher) not support http request.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562672/7687666
